# Why modal bootstrap on table data doesn't showing / fetching match data when popup?

Tags: forms, codeigniter, fetch, popup, bootstrap-modal

[Please check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlDH2.png)

I try to fetching data on every table data using modal bootstrap, but when i click every modal button it's just showing last table data in form of my popup modal. I want the data is per in the form on modal bootstrap. I am using CodeIgniter. Please help me, thanks. GBU

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped nowrap text-gray-900" id="dataTable" width="100%" style="font-size: 13px;" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="table-success">
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>NOMOR</th>
                            <th>KODE</th>
                            <th>TINDAKAN</th>
                            <th>AKSI</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        foreach ($prosedur_rehab as $rehab) {
                        ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?= $rehab->ID; ?></td>
                                <td><?= $rehab->NOMOR; ?></td>
                                <td><?= $rehab->KODE; ?></td>
                                <td><?= $rehab->TINDAKAN; ?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#perawat<?php echo $rehab->ID;?> ">
                                            <i class="fas fa-user-nurse"></i>
                                    </button>
                                    <div class="modal fade" id="perawat<?php echo $rehab->ID;?>" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
                                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" >
                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                    <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#5bc0de">
                                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Kelola Rawat Jalan (Diisi Oleh Perawat)</h5>
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                                        <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url().'dokter/kunjungan/kirimlaprajal'?>">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <!-- <label for="exampleInputEmail1">ID</label> -->
                                                                    <select name="" class="form-control">
                                                                        <option>-- CARI --</option>
                                                                        <?php foreach ($prosedur_rehab as $rehab):?>
                                                                            <option value="<?php echo $rehab->ID?>"><?php echo $rehab->ID?> || <?php echo $rehab->NORM?></option>
                                                                        <?php endforeach ?>
                                                                    </select>
                                                            </div>
                                                            
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">ID Prosedur</label>
                                                                <input type="text" name="ID" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" required readonly autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $rehab->ID; ?>">
                                                            </div>
                                                            
                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                <div class="col-6">
                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">No. Pendaftaran</label>
                                                                        <input type="text" name="NOMOR" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" required readonly autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $rehab->NOMOR; ?>">
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Kode</label>
                                                                        <input type="text" name="KODE" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" required readonly autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $rehab->KODE; ?>">
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Tindakan</label>
                                                                        <input type="text" name="TINDAKAN" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $rehab->TINDAKAN; ?>">
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Tanggal</label>
                                                                        <input type="datetime-local" name="TANGGAL" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" required autocomplete="off" placeholder="" value="">
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Instrumen Uji Fungsi</label>
                                                                        <input type="text" name="PROGRAM" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" required autocomplete="off" value="">
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Hasil</label>
                                                                        <input type="text" name="HASIL" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" required autocomplete="off" placeholder="" value="">
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col-6">
                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Kesimpulan</label>
                                                                        <input type="text" name="KESIMPULAN" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" required autocomplete="off" value="">
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Rekomendasi</label>
                                                                        <input type="text" name="REKOMENDASI" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" required autocomplete="off" value="">
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    
                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Oleh</label>
                                                                        <input type="text" name="OLEH" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" required autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $session_user->nip ;?>" readonly>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Status</label>
                                                                        <input type="text" name="STATUS" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" required autocomplete="off" value="">
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    
                                                                </div>
                                                                  
                                                            </div>
                                                            
                                                            <button type="submit" name="simpen" class="btn btn-info float-right"><i class="fas fa-save"> </i> Simpan</button>
                                                        </form>    
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div> 
                                        </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>NOMOR</th>
                            <th>KODE</th>
                            <th>TINDAKAN</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is i was used same foreach in select option . I was forgot if i 've been using first foreach to displaying table data and i used it again in form.

Don't using same foreach in form, delete or change this:

```
<select name="" class="form-control">
   <option>-- CARI --</option>
     <?php foreach ($prosedur_rehab as $rehab):?>
      <option value="<?php echo $rehab->ID?>"><?php echo $rehab->ID?> || <?php echo $rehab->NORM?></option>
     <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried your code and it works perfectly, Check your $rehave->ID value maybe it doesn't have value or have invalid value, or check your modal plugins [image]

Comment: If the problem in the question is not reproducible, then it should be flagged as such and not answered.

Comment: Thankyou verymuch for helping me, sir. But i already found the problem of this my own code. The problem is i was used same foreach in select option . I was forgot if i 've been using first foreach to displaying table data and i used it again in form. after i deleted it the program can work perfectly